# Unable to exclude projects in SonarQube from a specific directory

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've been working on getting our SonarQube setup on our code base but I'm having some odd difficulties with the exclusion process.  Our code directories are setup like this:

```
Main
   \Common\
   \Portal\
   \Tools\
```

We have various projects within each used in various combinations for Nuget projects or within solutions.  I've followed the examples of how to exclude projects for analysis and I can see that it works, but not always.  It seems I can exclude projects under Common or Tools just fine, but not under the Portal directory.

All the projects under the Portal directory show like in the image below.  I can exclude the BusinessObjects project fine, as the image below shows, so I know the process is working.  However, I can't seem to get the Contracts project to exclude at all.  All 3 csproj files have a property group designating what Sonar project they are associated to.

I have the targets file in the solution, I'm passing the correct value to MSBuild in the build, each project has a property group with a name in it.  Everything seems fine and working, as it is excluding one project, however, I just can't get anything under Portal to exclude.  I can exclude from any other directory just fine, just not Portal.

Is the directory Portal a reserved or special directory for Sonar?  Is there something obvious, and likely stupid on my part, that I'm missing?

[Sonar Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IWlN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Targets doesn't appear to always remove, powershell'ed the IsExcluded in the .sonarqube directory for the projects I wanted to exclude.  Seems like less work than modifying all my projects.